# Insert problem in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, oledb, constraints

> HRESULT: 0X80040E2F (DB_E_INTEGRITYVIOLATION)
>   Error message: Value violated the integrity constraints for a column or table.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: Which tables? Do `DESCRIBE` on the tables that are involved and paste the output here. Also show us the SQL you used that triggered this error.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is [an OLEDB error message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171852(SQL.100).aspx) meaning:

> "A specified value violated the
>   integrity constraints for a column or
>   table."

Utterly generic and not very helpful.  What it means is that one of the values you are attempting to insert into a table fails a database constraint.

There are several different types of constraint: unique / primary key constraints, foreign key constraints, NOT NULL and check constraints.   [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm)

Oracle has several database views which can provide you with information about the constraints in force for a given table. USER_CONSTRAINTS lists the constraints at the table level and USER_CONS_COLUMNS gives you information about the constrained columns.  (There are also ALL_ and DBA_ versions of these views, if the table's owner is not the user you're coonecting through).

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you are trying to insert a duplicate value for a unique key. If so, the solution is to not do that.